# Fit a spline to using several y-value data sets using SciPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

I'd like to generate a smoothed spline using a common set of x-values and three sets of y-values:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

ys1 = [0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.8, 0.7, 0.2, 0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 1.1]
ys2 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8, 0.3, 0.2, 0.9, 1.2, 1.2]
ys3 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.9, 0.3, 0.1, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9]
```

Looking at the spline documentation, I'm not sure if I am using the correct functions, but I'm trying to create my spline using [`RectBivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.html). What I'm trying to do is something like this, but I'm getting a number of errors, which makes me think I may be using the wrong function?

```
import scipy as scip
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

x_arr = scip.array(x_arr)
y_arr = scip.vstack((ys1, ys2, ys3))
spline = RectBivariate(x_arr, x_arr, y_arr)
```

Comment: Could you post the exception stack trace?  That will probably help determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RectBivariateSpline` is used with for a *3D-spline* where the Z coordinate is given as a 2D array, with each element `[i,j]` corresponding to the positions `x[i]` and `y[j]`.

In your case it looks more that you have 3 X *2D-splines*, which you can compute using:

```
import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import spline
xnew = scipy.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
ys1 = spline(xs, ys1, xnew, order=3)
ys2 = spline(xs, ys2, xnew, order=3)
ys3 = spline(xs, ys3, xnew, order=3)
```

If you want to take an average spline (like clarified in your comments):

```
ys = np.vstack((ys1,ys2,ys3)).mean(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. This is very close to what I'm looking for. However, instead of three splines I want one spline that smoothes based on all 3 sets of y-values. For example, at the x-value of 2, the smoothed spline might pass through 0.2 (between 0.1 and 0.3).